# How to avoid Duplication of CSS Classes while compile LESS to CSS

Tags: html, css, gruntjs, less

I am using less files for developing css but when I am compiling as css base.less get compile multiple times for eg:

```
style.less
   @import 'base.less'
   @import 'variable.less'
   @import '../../dashboard/my-dashboard.less'

my-dashboard.less
   @import 'base.less'
   .my-dashboard-css{
     all css goes here
}
```

when compiling style.less to style.css want to skip base.less from "my-dashboard.less" but i want to import base.less for reference for developer .Pls suggest me how to avoid me. Also Ihv tried @import(once) but its not working.

Comment: Can't you import them globally?

Comment: No I want to keep component driven folder system. My Dashboard is my component. want to keep all my dashboard resources in one folder and common variables and base files  in other folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can import only references using keyword `reference`: `@import (reference) "foo.less";`.

http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options

Answer (score 0):

I agree to @3rdthemagical answer. So for your answer follow the link as your guideline.

Here's probably your output in the end.

```
style.less
   @import (reference) 'base.less'
   @import (reference) 'variable.less'
   @import (less) '../../dashboard/my-dashboard.less'

my-dashboard.less
   @import (reference) 'base.less'
   .my-dashboard-css{
     all css goes here
}
```

and here's my actual LESS CSS

```
// CodeKit Framework Libraries [Bootstrap]
@import (reference) "utilities";
@import (reference) "variables";
@import (reference) "mixins";

// Internal Libraries
@import (less) "_fonts";
@import (less) "_mixins";
@import (less) "components/default";
@import (less) "components/menu";
@import (less) "components/header";
@import (less) "components/footer";

@import (less) "components/core";
```

**Note:** All under `reference` will be my variables and mixins. And if you declare your import as `less` it will read and import the file as less content.

Comment: Thanks for solution.. My problem get resolved by using latest Grunt package Version I am using 1.4.0 . It will automatic removed duplicate imported Less files from Output.CSS .